# Converting DATE to TEXT for use in SQL database

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, type-conversion

I'm currently making a simple note keeping application using sql database. I have three input fields (title, note, date). For the title and note I have input types TEXT, and for the date I have an input type DATE, where a popup calendar appears on clicking the text area, so the user can select from the calendar instead of having to type. 
However, I am having some issues with sending this date data to the sql, with the text either not appearing, or being undefined if I play around with the code. At the moment, the code is as follows and notes are not being added at all:

```
        //Test for browser compatibility
      if (window.openDatabase) {
      //Create the database the parameters are 1. the database name 2.version 
      number 3. a description 4. the size of the database (in bytes) 1024 x 1024 = 1MB
      var mydb = openDatabase("notes_db", "0.1", "A Database of Notes", 1024 * 
     1024);


     //create the notes table using SQL for the database using a transaction
    mydb.transaction(function(t) {
    t.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS notes (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY 
    ASC, title TEXT, note TEXT, vdate DATE)");  
     });



    } else {
    alert("WebSQL is not supported by your browser!");
     }

    //function to output the list of notes in the database

    function updateNoteList(transaction, results) {
    //initialise the listitems variable
       var listitems = "";
     //get the note list holder ul
        var listholder = document.getElementById("notelist");

   //clear notes list ul
      listholder.innerHTML = "";
      var i;

//Iterate through the results
    for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
      //Get the current row
      var row = results.rows.item(i);
      listholder.innerHTML += "<li>" + "<b>" + "<u>" + row.title
      + "</u>" + "</b>" + "<br>" + row.note + "<br>" + "<br>" + row.vdate + "
      (<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='deleteNote(" + row.id + 
      ");'>Delete Note</a>)" + "</li>" + "<br>" ;
     }

 }

     //function to get the list of notes from the database

  function outputNotes() {
   //check to ensure the mydb object has been created
    if (mydb) {
    //Get all the notes from the database with a select statement, set 
    outputNoteList as the callback function for the executeSql command
    mydb.transaction(function(t) {
        t.executeSql("SELECT * FROM notes", [], updateNoteList);
    });
} else {
    alert("db not found, your browser does not support web sql!");
}       



    function addNote() {
        //check to ensure the mydb object has been created
        if (mydb) {
       //get the values of the title and note text inputs
       var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
       var note = document.getElementById("note").value;
       var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
       //Test to ensure that the user has entered both a title and note
       if (title !== "" && note !== "") {
        //Insert the user entered details into the notes table, note the use 
        of the ? placeholder, these will replaced by the data passed in as 
        an array as the second parameter

      //here, the code had been as follows:
       //mydb.transaction(function(t) {
       //t.executeSql("INSERT INTO notes (title, note, date) VALUES (?, 
       //?,?)", [title, note, date]);
       //alert("Note successfully added");
       //});

        mydb.transaction(function(t) {
            t.executeSql("INSERT INTO notes (title, note, date) VALUES (?, 
            ?,TO_DATE('', DD/MM/YYYY))", [title, note, date]);
            alert("Note successfully added");
        });
    } else {
        alert("You must enter a title and note!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using `HTML5 WebSQL` which is actually `SQLite` under the hood. 
**In SQLite, there is no date data-type.** You have to store value as `TEXT` only.

Later you can use various `Date And Time Functions` for comparison, calculation and display purpose.

You can check documentation for more details on that.

Comment: Unfortunately, its still not working. No error is appearing, but when display notes is clicked, Only the header is appearing, but not the actual notes. Would you like to see the entire code, as perhaps the error is elsewhere?

Comment: Have you tried without `date` ? If you insert only title and note, is it working ? And there must be some error. Try to use something like try-catch to see if you can get some exceptions.

Comment: it works perfectly without the date. Title and note appear without any issue.

Comment: Try to check what value are you getting in `date` variable using `alert`. Also `date` is reserve keyword. So if possible, please rename that variable to, something like- `v_date`.

Comment: 'vdate' is returning the correct value as chosen in the calendar popup.

Comment: Can you share sample value ?

Comment: value is appearing in the alert as 2017/07/13.

Comment: Still no joy. Thanks for helping by the way. This is very frustrating, and I know you're giving up your time. I've tried changing the date field to just a text field that you can manually enter the date, rather than having a calendar display. This also doesnt work, so it must be an error elsewhere.

Comment: Looks like you are using `HTML5 WebSQL` which is actually `SQLite` under the hood. In SQLite you don't have `date` data-type. You have to store value as `TEXT` only. Later you can use various Date And Time Functions for comparison, calculation and display purpose

Comment: oh!! Thanks for pointing that out to me. I would have been at it all day

Comment: Sure. Request you please select my answer as correct answer to your question if this has solved your queries now.

Comment: Will do, one last thing. I've just edited the code so that date is now a text input. However, when the table is created, it has 2 id columns, and no date column. Thus date is appearing as undefined

Comment: Nevermind, I've figured it out. When I was editing back TEXT rather than DATE I accidentally renamed something.